# Microsoft Paint Selection Delete, gives Checkered Background

Tags: windows, microsoft, microsoft-paint

In Microsoft Paint, if I do, "selection rectangle", and then "delete", I get a checkered background.
This did not happen before.

I do Not have "Transparent selection" in settings.

How can I fix this? Currently using latest version Microsoft Paint 11.2308.30.0

This recently started occurring, and seems to be a bug in latest version.

[image]

[image]

Update per user comment:

Microsoft Paint now supports [layers and image transparency](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsoft-paint-finally-gets-support-for-layers-and-transparency/).

In this new version, "erasing content on one layer yields the effect of revealing the content on the layers beneath it." If the layer is empty, the placeholder is a checkered area.

[enter link description here](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsoft-paint-finally-gets-support-for-layers-and-transparency/)

Comment: I don't know Paint at all, but if you cut a hole in your only image layer, then there is nothing behind it. This is represented, in pretty much all graphics apps, as a grey/white check.

Comment: hi @Tetsujin yeah, this issue didnt happen last week, might be accidental setting change, however I can't find it, thanks

Comment: In photoshop, if your background layer is locked, rather than cutting a hole, you are offered a fill instead, where you can choose either a plain colour, or 'smart' fill based on the surrounding image. If the layer is unlocked - you get a hole.

Comment: hi @Tetsujin can you write a solution and I can send points? thanks

Comment: I believe it's what's referred to as an alpha channel.

Comment: i had this exact same problem! i wonder why this happened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To restore a white background, here's a possible solution:

- Click the `Layers` icon.
- Click `Create new layer` icon. Drag it to the bottom.
- Click `Show Layer`. Flood fill it with a white background.
- Click `Hide Layer`. Select the original image.

Now when editing your original image, it'll behave like the old paint tool.

[image: white-bkg]

Comment: So many steps, would need to save and load a `blank.png` and hope I don't overwrite it. Resizing (increasing) top image reveals checkerboard, I figure no way around it?

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft Paint now supports [layers and image transparency](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsoft-paint-finally-gets-support-for-layers-and-transparency/).

In this new version, "erasing content on one layer yields the effect of revealing the content on the layers beneath it." If the layer is empty, the placeholder is a checkered area.

Comment: Ahhh, that's why. I really don't know Paint at all, so I wouldn't have even guessed it wasn't capable of transparency until now. Makes perfect sense.

Comment: thanks, so how do I get it back to the original functionality? I want to get white background,  or are you saying its not possible anymore? no workaround?

Comment: It is possible to uninstall MS Paint, https://winaero.com/uninstall-microsoft-paint-in-windows-10-mspaint/ , but finding a **safe** copy of the old version might be difficult. From FileHorse: "This software is no longer available for the download." Suggestion: either learn to live with it, or try one of the *many* alternatives: https://alternativeto.net/software/microsoft-paint/

Comment: @mattsmith5 Where's this complaining that I can join?

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon, , you might get more satisfaction from Python arguments: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLlv_aZjHXc

Comment: I just added your comments in the question, not really answer, just explaining Microsoft issues, going with vengy answer workaround for right now, thanks

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Do you have a knowledge on which of the seven listed "best Paint alternatives" does _not_ have the same feature? I am pretty sure that Paint.NET has exactly the same way of handling background (i.e. supporting transparency channel).

Comment: For general image editing, I use IrfanView, which does *not* have layers, the feature you want top avoid. It is not as good as paint for drawing a new image, but has *many* other features I use., That said, this site is **not for software recommendations.**

Answer (score 0):

This feature ([layers and image transparency](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsoft-paint-finally-gets-support-for-layers-and-transparency/)) seems to be introduced in [September 2023](https://beebom.com/microsoft-paint-background-removal-how-use/) and doesn't actually allow to be turned off.

Doing what [*vengy* proposes](https://superuser.com/a/1814473/156554) for each and every image being edited is a natural madness and will drive even the most sane person crazy.

What worked for me was to [uninstall Paint and replace it with a classic version](https://onezeronull.com/2023/11/09/deleting-or-moving-selection-in-paint-reveals-emptiness/):

1. Uninstalling can be done by simply right-clicking Paint icon in Start Menu and selecting *Uninstall* from context menu.
2. *Classic Paint* can be get from [here](https://win7games.com/#mspaint) or [here](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/get-windows-10-classic-paint-in-windows-11/?expand_article=1#:%7E:text=Download%20Paint%20(Classic).zip).
3. Download and install it.
4. Go to *Settings* → *Apps* → *Apps & Features* → *More settings* → *App execution aliases*.
5. Toggle the switch to *Off* for *mspaint.exe* and *pbrush.exe* items:

A thing to consider is pinning *Classic Paint*‘s icon to Start Menu or taskbar.

The biggest advantage of this change is of course to get ol' good "remove to background color" feature.

But the nifty addition was to get "Edit with Classic Paint" option in image files' context menu. Long time considered lost and very happily welcomed back (the *Open with* → *Paint* dual click feature was driving me crazy, honestly speaking).